# FOSUserbundle - How to add new role?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOS Userbundle and I want to add new role such as ROLE_ZZZ.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think a valid (clean and simple enough) way to create a new role and integrate it with FOSUserBundle is

1) Add a new role through `security.yml`

```
security:
  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ZZZ: [ROLE_USER, OTHER_PERMISSION_1, OTHER_PERMISSION_2, ...]
```

2) Create a FOSUserBundle group ([group handling doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html)) and asign that role (and only that role) to the group.

Then users can be added to that group as you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The `FOSUserbundle` does not provide a role-entity. You have to implement it yourself by implementing the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface`.

It should look like [this role-entity](https://gist.github.com/jmoz/1423700#file-role-php).

After that you have to create the user-role relationship and assign the role to the user.
A full tutorial can be found here [to implement a new role in fosuserbundle](http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities/).